# How to give hint for jEditorPane?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jeditorpane

How can I give hint for jEditorPane in Java, I am using NetBeans ide? I don't see any property in the jEditorPane, what can be done in this respect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By hint you mean a tooltip?

```
editor.setToolTipText("Tooltip here");
```

You should be able to find a `toolTipText` property in the properties for the pane.

Comment: I want something like hint which we use in android, ie it should appear inside the editor but should disappear on the click, is there any way to do that?